# css child selector expression understanding confuses about the following code walk through

Tags: css, css-selectors

In CSS what does it mean by this?  .wb is a class and I also understand that .wb-chIld may be its child classes which inherits properties of that. now what is the > and * ?   under which circumstances we write code like this?

```
.wb, .wb-child > * {
     border-width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: `.wb-child > *` means all types of immediate childs of `.wb-child`

Answer (score 1):

Lets break it down shall we.

So we have:

```
.wb, .wb-child > * {
     border-width: 2px;
}
```

`.wb`: is a class, anything with this class will have the following defined styles.

`.wb, .wb-child > *`: Now we have a comma `,` this allows us to have more then one selector on a style. So in this case there are 2 selectors, both `.wb` and `.wb-child > *`.

`.wb-child > *`: Now lets take a look at what this is selecting. It is pointing at `.wb-child` and selecting all (`*` selects all elements) the immediate children of that class.

Lets take a look at this in a demo.

```css
.wb,
.wb-child > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wb">
  This is some test text.
  <div class="wb-child">
    <span>I am a immediate span child of .wb-child</span>
    <div>I am a immediate div child of .wb-child
      <div>I am a child of this div, not an immediate child of .wb-child</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this demo we are giving a border to `.wb` **and** all of `.wb-child` children ( `> *`). Please note that `.wb-child` itself does not have a border, only its children do.

Also the `div` that is inside of `.wb-child` `div` is also not affected, this is due to it not being an immediate child of `.wb-child`.

To learn more about `*` selector [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: @misterManSam is right, only the immediate child `wb1` will have the `border-width: 2px` style applied

'.wb-child > *' meant all tags after the 'wb-child' class. Refer to your example with below HTML codes:

```
<div class="wb-cihld">
  <div class="wb1">
    <div class="wb2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<s>Both 'wb1' and 'wb2' classes will have the 'border-width: 2px;' style applied.</s>

Comment: `.wb-child > *` will target *all direct* children of `.wb-child`. The `.wb2` in your snippet will not have that style applied as it is not a direct child.